# Error: Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop for the screen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application, bottomnavigationview

I am using bottom navigation in react-native application. I have created MainContainer.js file under src/screen/ and other three files are also created at same path. Now when I am running my project then I am getting below error.

```
ERROR  Error: Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop for the screen 'MainContainer'. This can happen if you passed 'undefined'. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or mixed up default import and named import when importing.
```

Code of maincontainer.js file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import ActivityScreen from './ActivityScreen';
import AccountScreen from './AccountScreen';

const MainContainer = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'HomeScreen', title: 'Home', focusedIcon: 'home', unfocusedIcon: 'home-outline'},
    { key: 'ActivityScreen', title: 'Activity', focusedIcon: 'trending-up'},
    { key: 'AccountScreen', title: 'Account', focusedIcon: 'account', unfocusedIcon: 'account-outline'},    
  ]);

  const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
    ActivityScreen: ActivityScreen,
    AccountScreen: AccountScreen,
  });
  return (
    <BottomNavigation
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      barStyle={{backgroundColor:'white'}}
    />
  );
};

export default MainContainer;
```

code of ActivityScreen.js and code of other two files are similar

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Header from '../components/Header'

export default function AccountScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
      <Header>Restore Password</Header>
  )
}
```